# iOS:Dispaly label with text on collectionView cell on long press

Tags: ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I want to display label with text on collectionViewCell on long press.
Text which i want to display is coming from array.

Following is my code:

```
// This code is in cellForItemAtIndexPath method
// attach long press gesture to collectionView
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr= [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[collectionViewAlbumImages addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;






-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    return;
}
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:collectionViewAlbumImages];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionViewAlbumImages indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
if (indexPath == nil){
    NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
} else {
    // get the cell at indexPath (the one you long pressed)
    UICollectionViewCell* cell =[collectionViewAlbumImages cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    globalVariable = [GlobalBrogaard sharedInstanceMethod];

    strCellImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[globalVariable.arrImageName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"cell %f , %f",cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y);
    // Init and add label
    lblImageName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 200, 200)];
    lblImageName.layer.cornerRadius=6;
    lblImageName.clipsToBounds=NO;
    lblImageName.text = strCellImageName;
    [lblImageName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    lblImageName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    lblImageName.numberOfLines = 0;

    lblImageName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    lblImageName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblImageName.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.6];
    [lblImageName sizeToFit];


    [cell addSubview:lblImageName];

    [lblImageName setAlpha:0.0f];

    //fade in
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

        [lblImageName setAlpha:1.0f];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        //fade out
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{

            [lblImageName setAlpha:0.0f];
            [lblImageName removeFromSuperview];

        } completion:nil];

    }];
}}
```

but issue is it works only for first collection view cell long press and on remaining cells it will not display any label.
Please tell me what is wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by changing this line:

```
lblImageName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, 200, 200)];
```

to:

```
lblImageName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 200)];
```